# How can I centralize <nb-select> control

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm using Nebular Template.

I'm trying to use `<nb-select>`.

I couldn't centralize the control, once it as been inside another tag, `<div class="input-group">`, for example.

How could I centralize the `<nb-select>`, and how could I set 100% of width of this control, and the change has been visible at the control?

```
          <div class="input-group">
              <nb-select selected="0">
                <nb-option value="1">Verint Speech</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="2">Nice IA</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
            </div>
```

Comment: By "centralize" do you mean center? That is, are you trying to position the element such that it is centered horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I centralize the

According to code from the question you have `nb-select` inside `div` with `input-group` class. To center `nb-select` inside `div` add following CSS to your component:

```
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

> how could I set 100% of width of this control

You can set `fullWidth` input of `nb-select`.

```
<nb-select fullWidth>
...
</nb-select>
```

See the [docs for details](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/select/api#nbselectcomponent)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Funny enough it's  case sensitive, thus `fullwidth` wouldn't  work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override default CSS and force max-widht to 100% as follows. This worked for me.

```
nb-select{ 
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use the offered solution by the library `fullWidth`.